# optimize sql query on 5B records table in postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

My postgresql database has the table `electrical_measurement` which contains approximately 5 billion records. I have indexes on every column. I am trying to perform the following query but it never ends. Wondering how I can modify it to run faster.

```
SELECT
    em.id AS em_id,
    em.test_board_id_in,
    em.die,
    tvt_net.name,
    mb_pad_map.x,
    mb_pad_map.y,
    em.temperature,
    em.timestamp,
    em.avg_meas_voltage
FROM electrical_measurement AS em
INNER JOIN main_board_pad_map AS mb_pad_map
    ON em.net_id_in = mb_pad_map.net_id
INNER JOIN tvt_net
    ON em.net_id_in = tvt_net.id
WHERE em.assembly_id = 1
AND em.net_id_in IN 
 (SELECT em.net_id_in 
  FROM electrical_measurement AS em
  WHERE em.assembly_id = 1
  AND em.avg_meas_voltage > 0
  GROUP BY em.net_id_in)
ORDER BY em.timestamp
```

This is the result from `EXPLAIN`:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=373158311.30..573643901.29 rows=1718327938 width=63)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=373157311.28..375305221.20 rows=859163969 width=63)
         Sort Key: em."timestamp"
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=84935808.04..171830022.94 rows=859163969 width=63)
               Hash Cond: (em.net_id_in = mb_pad_map.net_id)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=84935424.26..161155613.60 rows=118993479 width=41)
                     Hash Cond: (em.net_id_in = em_1.net_id_in)
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on electrical_measurement em  (cost=2996320.29..78903135.78 rows=118993479 width=37)
                           Recheck Cond: (assembly_id = 1)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on electrical_measurement_assembly_id_idx  (cost=0.00..2924924.21 rows=285584350 width=0)
                                 Index Cond: (assembly_id = 1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=81939087.68..81939087.68 rows=1303 width=4)
                           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=81939061.62..81939074.65 rows=1303 width=4)
                                 Group Key: em_1.net_id_in
                                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on electrical_measurement em_1  (cost=2953194.68..81656356.93 rows=113081878 width=4)
                                       Recheck Cond: (assembly_id = 1)
                                       Filter: (avg_meas_voltage > '0'::numeric)
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on electrical_measurement_assembly_id_idx  (cost=0.00..2924924.21 rows=285584350 width=0)
                                             Index Cond: (assembly_id = 1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=266.17..266.17 rows=9408 width=38)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=42.32..266.17 rows=9408 width=38)
                           Hash Cond: (mb_pad_map.net_id = tvt_net.id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on main_board_pad_map mb_pad_map  (cost=0.00..199.08 rows=9408 width=16)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=26.03..26.03 rows=1303 width=22)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on tvt_net  (cost=0.00..26.03 rows=1303 width=22)
(26 rows)
```

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: It's the correlated subquery.

Comment: Can you please post DDL and perhaps some sample data, ideally as a SQLFiddle?

Comment: Wait... can you use two different aliases instead of `em` twice? That only complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

The sub-select only is one of your issues, but you could use [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) instead:

```sql
SELECT
    em.id AS em_id,
    em.test_board_id_in,
    em.die,
    tvt_net.name,
    mb_pad_map.x,
    mb_pad_map.y,
    em.temperature,
    em.timestamp,
    em.avg_meas_voltage
FROM electrical_measurement AS em
INNER JOIN main_board_pad_map AS mb_pad_map
    ON em.net_id_in = mb_pad_map.net_id
INNER JOIN tvt_net
    ON em.net_id_in = tvt_net.id
WHERE em.assembly_id = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM electrical_measurement AS tmp
  WHERE tmp.avg_meas_voltage > 0
  AND tmp.net_id_in = em.net_id_in)
ORDER BY em.timestamp
```

Then, you should have an index covering at least both, `net_id_in` and `avg_meas_voltage`. By that, you should be eliminating the `Bitmap Heap Scan`, the `Group Key` and the `HashAggregate` in one shot.

Last but not least, you are dealing with time-series information and you are querying all of the data, sorted by time, which is going to be really slow (most likely reverting to a disk sort, instead of in-memory) with so many estimated rows (~1.7B).

If you really, really need all of the data from the beginning of all time in your big table **and** you really need to sort it, then make sure that you have a separate low-latency, high-throughput storage available, create a tablespace and set [`temp_tablespaces`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES) option to it (disk sorts then will go there instead of the default tablespace).

Comment: Outstanding answer.

Comment: Needed to update as I did a false assumption on column correlation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try window functions:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT em.*,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE em.assembly_id = 1 AND em.avg_meas_voltage) OVER (PARTITION BY em.net_id_in) as cnt
      FROM electrical_measurement em
     ) em JOIN
     main_board_pad_map mbpm
     ON em.net_id_in = mbpm.net_id JOIN
     tvt_net
     ON em.net_id_in = tv.id
WHERE em.assembly_id = 1 AND
      cnt > 0
ORDER BY em.timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery is the killer. Need to remove it and do it another way. Thanks for your comments.